# XSLT WMS GetCapabilities to JSON

Tags: json, xml, xslt, saxon, saxon-js

I am trying to convert the GetCapabilities of the GeoMet WMS XML response.data to a JSON that can be used in a `v-treeview` Vuetify component such as [in this link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/#search-and-filter).

```
testfunc: function () {
      axios.get('https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?lang=en&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities').then((response) => {
        const xslt = `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:output method="json" build-tree="no"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/Layer" priority="5">
    <xsl:map>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:map>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <xsl:map-entry key="local-name()" select="data()"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Layer[1]">
    <xsl:map-entry key="'children'">
      <xsl:sequence select="array { mf:apply-templates(*) }"/>
    </xsl:map-entry>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Layer[position() > 1]"/>
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:apply-templates" as="item()*">
    <xsl:param name="elements" as="element(*)*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$elements"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>`
        const jsonResult = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`
          transform(
            map { 
              'source-node' : parse-xml($xml), 
              'stylesheet-text' : $xslt, 
              'delivery-format' : 'raw' 
            }
            )?output`,
        [],
        { 'params': { 'xml': response.data, 'xslt': xslt } }
        )
        console.log(jsonResult)
      })
    }
```

My test function returns all the infromations and does not really parse the XML response the way I need it to and I am new to XSLT. I need something that will return only the `<Name>` and `<Title>` innerHTML of the `<Layer>` tags and their children in arrays called `children` that looks like :

```
{
title: 'Title Level 1'
name: 'Name Level 1'
children: [
    {
     title: 'Title Level 2'
     name: 'Name Level 2'
     children: [
         {
          title: 'Title Level 3-1'
          name: 'Name Level 3-1'
         },
         {
          title: 'Title Level 3-2'
          name: 'Name Level 3-2'
         }
     ]
]
}
```

EDIT : Sample XML of the [full XML](https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?lang=en&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities) which has one root with only a title that has 14 groups of

```
<Layer queryable="1">
<Title>MSC GeoMet — GeoMet-Weather 2.14.1</Title>
   <Layer queryable="1">
   <Name>Regional Deterministic Prediction System (RDPS) [10 km]</Name>
   <Title>Regional Deterministic Prediction System (RDPS) [10 km]</Title>
      <Layer queryable="1">
      <Name>RDPS - Coupled to Gulf of St. Lawrence (RDPS-CGSL)</Name>
      <Title>RDPS - Coupled to Gulf of St. Lawrence (RDPS-CGSL)</Title>
         <Layer queryable="1" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
         <Name>CGSL.ETA_ICEC</Name>
         <Title>CGSL.ETA.ICEC - Ice cover fraction</Title>
...
```

Comment: It is not clear what your input XML format is so at least show a small but representative sample of that.

Comment: I have added the link to the full XML Mr. Honnen and a very small sample of it in the edit of the original post. There are nested Layer tags all of which have Names and Titles and I need all of the names and titles so I can build a tree view visualizer.

Comment: It would help is if you indent the sample and cut it to contain the essential data. Can a singe Layer have more than one Name or more than one Title child element? What kind of JSON do you want to create in that case?

Comment: One note:  I introduced you to `SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate` as one way to run XSLT code directly but take into account that the more efficient way in both the browser and with Node.js is the pre-compile from the XML based XSLT code to the JSON based SEF format with either Saxon EE or with the `xslt3` command line tool to then simply run the `SaxonJS.transform` JavaScript method to execute the SEF code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSLT 3 sample to process only `Layer` elements (in that particular namespace `http://www.opengis.net/wms`) and the first `Title` and `Name` plus recursively the child `Layer`s would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.opengis.net/wms"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:output method="json" build-tree="no" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/WMS_Capabilities/Capability/Layer" priority="5">
    <xsl:map>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:map>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Layer/Title[1] | Layer/Name[1]">
    <xsl:map-entry key="local-name()" select="data()"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Layer[1]">
    <xsl:map-entry key="'children'">
      <xsl:sequence select="array { ../Layer/mf:apply-templates(.) }"/>
    </xsl:map-entry>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Layer[position() > 1]"/>
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:apply-templates" as="item()*">
    <xsl:param name="elements" as="element(*)*"/>
    <xsl:map>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$elements/*"/>      
    </xsl:map>
  </xsl:function>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You have claimed me as a worshipper and I dennounce the false Gods that are Dimitre Novatchev and Michael Kay. Thank you so much sir. Your Solution is perfect and I think I understand more about XSLT because of that.

Comment: Don't do Dimitre or Michael injustice, thanks to Michael efforts (and company Saxonica) we have both the XSLT 2  and 3 specification plus the Saxon implementations of the spec, including Saxon-JS running in the browser and with Node.js where browser vendors or JavaScript companies certainly wouldn't have made any effort to support XML related innovations. And Dimitre for a reason became the first XML and XSLT gold star on StackOverflow, and his XPath Visualizer was certainly a tool that helped me to enter in the world of XSLT and XPath years ago.